# VBA - Results of distVincenty() into Variable

Tags: excel, vba, geo

I am writing some code to calculate geological distances. Therefore I use the public function **distVincenty()** you can find here....

https://www.contextures.com/excellatitudelongitude.html

It works pretty well but as soon, I try to put the results into a variable I get an error in VBA. What am I doing wrong?

See my code......

```
Sub Tourenplaner()

Dim Sht As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Sheets("Tourenplaner").Activate
Set Sht = Sheets("Auswertung_Tourenplaner")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Sheets.Add , ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Auswertung_Tourenplaner"
    Range("A1").Resize(, 4) = Array("Zeile", "Breitengrad", "Längengrad", "Distanz")

    Err.Clear
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Set Sht = Sheets("Auswertung_Tourenplaner")
    Sheets("Tourenplaner").Activate
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Dim A_lon(90) As Double
Dim A_lat(90) As Double
Dim J_lat(90) As Double
Dim J_lon(90) As Double
Dim Summe1(90) As Double
Dim Summe2(90) As Double


'Auswertung
    'Welche Zeilen wurden bereits bearbeitet?
    m = Application.Max(Sht.Columns(1)) 'Keine Ahnung, was das ist...m ist immer 3 -> der Startwert von i in Spalte A
    m = IIf(m > 2, m, 2) 'Die Zahl ist hier die Zeile, ab der die Daten beginnen
    lr = Sht.Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Zeilennummer durchlaufend

For i = m To Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'i ist Spalte A und ist ein Zähler, wenn eine neue Zeile mit Geodaten beginnt, wird der Zähler hochgesetzt
    fl = False
    Tx = Replace(Cells(i, 6), ",", "|") 'Die Zahl hinter dem i ist hier die Spalte in der die Geodaten stehen!
    Ar = Split(Replace(Tx, ".", ","), "|")
    For b = 0 To UBound(Ar) Step 2
        lr = lr + 1
        A_lon(i) = CDbl(Ar(0))
        A_lat(i) = CDbl(Ar(1))
        J_lon(i) = CDbl(Ar(UBound(Ar) - 1))
        J_lat(i) = CDbl(Ar(UBound(Ar)))
        If m - i = 0 Then
        End If
        Sht.Cells(lr, 1) = i
        Sht.Cells(lr, 2) = CDbl(Ar(b))
        Sht.Cells(lr, 3) = CDbl(Ar(b + 1))
        Sht.Cells(lr, 5) = lr
        Sht.Cells(lr, 6) = Tx 'Alle Geodaten in Punktschreibweise einer Strecke in einer Zelle getrennt mit | - ändert sich erst wieder wenn sich der Wert in Spalte A ändert
        Sht.Cells(lr, 7) = Ar 'A1 lon
        Sht.Cells(lr, 9) = b
        Sht.Cells(lr, 10) = Application.Max(Sht.Columns(1)) 'Entspricht exakt der Zeile A
        Sht.Cells(lr, 11) = m
        Sht.Cells(lr, 13) = A_lat(i)
        Sht.Cells(lr, 14) = J_lon(i)
        Sht.Cells(lr, 15) = J_lat(i)
        Sht.Cells(lr, 16) = A_lon(i)
        If fl Then Sht.Cells(lr, 4) = distVincenty(Ar(b - 2), Ar(b - 1), Ar(b), Ar(b + 1))
        fl = True
    Next b
Next i

For i = m To Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Summe1(i) = distVincenty(J_lon(i), J_lat(i), A_lon(i + 1), A_lat(i + 1))
            If m - i <> 0 Then
                Summe2(i) = distVincenty(J_lon(i - 1), J_lat(i - 1), A_lon(i), A_lat(i))
            Else
                Summe2(i) = distVincenty(A_lon(i), A_lat(i), A_lon(i + 1), A_lat(i + 1))
            End If
Next i

Sheets("Auswertung_Tourenplaner").Activate

End Sub
```

The problem is here....

```
Summe1(i) = distVincenty(J_lon(i), J_lat(i), A_lon(i + 1), A_lat(i + 1))
```

does not work. Displaying the results of the function into a cell is no problem. But as soon I try to put the results into a variable, I get an error.

Comment: What is the error message? How many rows are you dealing with?

Comment: Not sure what this bit is for: `If m - i = 0 Then End If`

Comment: It is a Runtime-error '9'  pointing to the line above. Not many rows...7.

Comment: Then i > 91 what is `m` at that point?

Comment: m is at 8 when debugging

Comment: You are right. There is a problem with the loop. Thank you!